# bottom of Silverlight 3 control cut off with no vertical scrollbar if it is too big for browser window

Tags: silverlight, silverlight-3.0

I have a silverlight control on a page.  It is set to "Width=100% Height=100%", and the containing div is set to an absoulute position with "0" on all edges.  On a small screen, when the silverlight content is taller than the screen, the bottom is cut off, and there is no scroll bar.  Does anyone know how to solve this problem?

Answer (score 1):

Wrap the control in a [ScrollViewer.](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.scrollviewer%28VS.95%29.aspx)

Comment: That doesn't work.  The silverlight plugin is tall enough to handle the content, but the plugin itself is being lost off the bottom of the screen with no scrollbar.  I have tried setting the overflow to auto and scroll, to no avail.